# Centering an unknown width Lightbox

Tags: html, css, lightbox

I've looked at some other threads, but nothing seems to work. I'm trying to center a lightbox of an unknown width in the center of the page (horizontally). Any help would be appreciated. The code is as follows.

HTML

```
<div class="backdrop"></div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="close">x</div>
    <img src="../pics/placeholder.png">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: .0;
  filter:alpha(opacity=0);
  z-index: 50;
  display: none;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  z-index: 51;
  padding: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444444;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444444;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444444;
  display: none;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 98%
  margin-top: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

• To center an element horizontally with **`position: relative`** use:

```
.element {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto; /* We don't care about 0, but we do care about auto. */
}
```

• To center an element horizontally with **`position: absolute`** or **`position: fixed`** use:

```
.element {
    position: fixed; /* Lightboxes usually use position: fixed. */
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: YOU ARE AN AMAZING PERSON. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad I could help @BJohnson